# Access Individual Style Elements of JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to build a color guessing game using JS. I have used a color array with list of initial colors. So far, the whole code works until I try to show an alert when each square is clicked with the current color.

In console I get error as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
>       at HTMLDivElement. (color_game.js:25)

line 25 points to this:

```
var clickedColor = squares[i].style.background;
```

Here, I am trying to get reference to style of each square in the array. (Look at src below)

It says sth is undefined on further inspection.

My full code is attached below:
HTML:

```
<body>

  <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisp">RGB</span> Guessing Game</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="square">

    </div>
    <div class="square">

    </div>
    <div class="square">

    </div>
    <div class="square">

    </div>
    <div class="square">

    </div>
    <div class="square">

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="color_game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var colorArr = [
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colorArr[3];
var colorDisp = document.getElementById("colorDisp");
colorDisp.innerHTML = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].style.background = colorArr[i];

  squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var clickedColor = squares[i].style.background;
    alert(clickedColor);

    if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
      alert("CORRECT");
    } else {
      alert("WRONG COLOR!!!");
    }

  });
}
```

I have tried these two lines, but my code doesn't execute:

```
var clickedColor = squares[i].style.background;
```

and

```
var clickedColor = this.style.background;
```

Can someone point out to me how to access the style elements of an array in JS?

Comment: try changing the line that throws an error to `var clickedColor = event.target.style.background;`

Comment: You might want to put a `console.log(i)` above that line, and then check your browser console ... (I just wonder, will we ever get _closure_ on the endless stream of questions about this particular issue ...?)

Answer (score 1):

I did 2 small changes and it worked for me.

Modified HTML part to add some text for `<div>`. e.g.

```
   <div id="container">
        <div class="square">
            A
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            B
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            C
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            D
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            E
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            F
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then modified line

`var clickedColor = squares[i].style.background;`

to

`var clickedColor = this.style.background;`

it works correctly for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event to get the target element.

```
squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  var clickedColor = e.target.style.background;
  alert(clickedColor);

  if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
    alert("CORRECT");
  } else {
    alert("WRONG COLOR!!!");
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It works now. Can someone explain to me how e.target.style.background works. Thanks again

Comment: "e" is the event object that java script passes to any call back of an event listener. This object contains information about the event(click in this case) like on what tag the user clicked, type of event and so on.